# Cells add or remove to the formula dynamically if there values only

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have % values on A1 to G1.

In H1 I have a multiplication formula: `(A1*B1*C1*D1*E1*F1*G1)`.

But I have only values in A2 to F2 and A3 to C3, A4 to E4. There is no pattern.

How can I write a formula or vba code for get values for H1, H2, H3, H4 without removing or adding cells which contain values manually?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Use the [`PRODUCT`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/product-function-8e6b5b24-90ee-4650-aeec-80982a0512ce) function:

```
=PRODUCT(A2:G2)
```

[image]